# apache fails to get remote host name

Tags: apache-2.4

I have...

```
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com

    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

which immediately goes to...

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost example.com:443>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias example.com

        DocumentRoot /home/klyde/ror/exampledev/public

        SSLCertificateFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/123abc.crt
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private/examplekey.key

        BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProxyEngine On
        ProxyRequests On

        <Proxy *>
            AddDefaultCharset off
            #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride none
            <RequireAny>
                #<RequireAll>
                #   Require all granted
                #</RequireAll>
                <RequireAll>
                    Require host example.com
                </RequireAll>
                <RequireAll>
                    Require local
                    # Require ip 127.0.0.1
                </RequireAll>
            </RequireAny>
        </Proxy>

        ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /
        ProxyPass /errors/ !

        ProxyPass /websockets ws://127.0.0.1:8675/
        ProxyPassReverse /websockets ws://127.0.0.1:8675/

        ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
        ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

When I enable...

```
Require all granted
```

all works ok. But the site is overrun by phishing.
I would like...

```
Require host example.com
```

But this results in a log error...

```
access check of 'example.com' to / failed, reason: unable to get the remote host name
```

This configuration I've chosen because I want to stop SSL in Apache and ajp to Torquebox. This works fine, except when attempting to secure the site. Of course, Apache with Torquebox may not be entirely desirable, advisable, etc. Suggestions to the contrary are welcome.

Main question - Why the 'remote host name' error. Any ideas?

Comment: Does name resolution work for other services on the box?

Comment: The 'name resolution'...I can't say that it does. All I know is that it all works with 'Require all granted'. But then, no security.

Answer (score 2):

Determining the remote host by name only works if the remote IP address has a `PTR` records,  Not all IP addresses do.  If you can, use IP addresses in the `Require` statement.

You can also use basic auth (preferably over https) to restrict access.

You should not need to define a `proxy` if all you want is `proxypass` functionality.

If you need to proxy, try restricting your proxy to your domain.

```
<Proxy http://www.example.com/*>
    ....
</Proxy>
```

Comment: Using full address in <Proxy> with "Require if xx.xxx.xx.xxx" - immediate success. Also, completely removing the forward proxy, <Proxy>, and it's directives, works. I'll keep it this way. In both scenarios, Chrome still gives the Phishing warning, although no further evidence of it. Firefox now gives NO warning. No errors, just blocked attempts are logged. Suspect this is normal. I'd vote you up, if i had enough points.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

`Require ip 127.0.0.1`

with IP from your server instad of the local ip

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to open things up and allow requests coming from any IP you can use:

```
Require all granted
```

You can look here for more info: https://serverfault.com/a/887196/468080